# Unity - 14.04 - Set Launcher Icon Size - via command line

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, scripts, icons

I've got a few computers, all coming to the end of their life.

The first couple have gone and I find myself again having to re-install ubuntu on it's resurrected remains and then laboriously reconfigure everything.

So I'm writing a couple of scripts to reconfigure the thing back to how I like it... and install all the core programs I need to work.

Ideally i'd do `Sudo ./install.sh` walk away, make some tea and avoid the headache.

So far I've got:

```
# Turn on workspaces
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 2

# Turn on hide launcher
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 1
```

Could anyone advise how I'd auto set launcher icon size to a number (probably 36 in this case) and similarly what the command would be for the auto hide launcher sensitivity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to do this using dconf e.g. to set the launcher icon size to 64 pixels

Code:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size 64
```

To reset it to the default value, you can use

Code:

```
dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size
```

The dconf command line utility is not installed by default - you need to install the dconf-tools package. Usually there is an equivalent command via gsettings however in this case it appears the required schema definition does not exist.

Source : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195187

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar - that works perfectly many thanks.

Comment: Bonus question for anyone around... why does this work with dconf and the others use gsettings?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: This does work with gsettings too: ``gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 64`` note the trailing slash, which is required.

Comment: thanks, works on Ubuntu 16.04.2. Interesting enough, it doesn't change size of launcher icons when running on virtual machine (same ubuntu version)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you want to copy most/all settings for all gnome-based apps (like gedit, launchers, etc., Unity included) from one account to another, you can use `dconf dump / > mysettings.ini` and on the target account: `dconf load / < mysettings.ini`.

In addition, you could manually review all the setting in `mysettings.ini` and adapt them as needed (you'll find there the `icon-size` and everything else related to Unity).

If you can't identify a particular setting by looking through the dump, you could find it by first doing a dump, then changing the setting via the standard UI, then comparing the original dump with a new one, like this:

`dconf dump / > ~/tmp.dump`

change a setting via the UI

`diff -B5 <(dconf dump /) ~/tmp.dump`

(`-B5` is to additionally get 5 lines before the match, for more context -OR- use `dconf watch /`)

The settings that are dumped with `dconf dump /` are the values that *differ* from the defaults, i.e. you won't see there settings that currently have their default values. For a complete list of all available settings with rather complete explanations, possible ranges and default values check the files in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`. You'll see there `10_xxx.override` files, this is the preferred way to override the settings globally.

As to the comment by @mauek-unak, compiz settings (like the `icon-size`) were not working under a VM because the default compiz profile under low graphics is `unity-lowgfx`, but the setting modified by `gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/uni‌​tyshell/ icon-size 64` is for the `unity` profile. The strange thing is that even with `dconf dump/load` the setting of the current profile `gsettings get org.compiz current-profile` is not having effect on the actual compiz profile.

When lowgfx is in play, `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config` will have some settings and you should change it with something like:

`sed -i '/profile = / s/-lowgfx//g' ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config`

The change is applied immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when running Ubuntu under VirtualBox, you will need to do:

gsettings set com.canonical.Unity lowgfx false

Editing the config file will only temporarily change it.